# How to use a custom middleware with nestjs-telegraf?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, telegram-bot, prisma

I am trying to implement custom Telegraf middleware with nestjs-telegraf library and connection to DB using Prisma.
My AppModule is:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TelegrafModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule, LoggerModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService, logger: LoggerMiddleware) => {    
        return {
          token: configService.get<string>("TELEGRAM_TOKEN")!,
          middlewares: [sessionMiddleware, logger.use]
        };
      },
      inject: [ConfigService, LoggerMiddleware]
    }),
    PrismaModule
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [...someProviders]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

LoggerMiddleware:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoggerMiddleware {
  constructor(private readonly prisma: PrismaService) {}

  async use(ctx: Context, next: NextFunction) {
    const listUser = await this.prisma.user.findMany()
    console.log('listUser = ', listUser)
    next()
  }
}
```

LoggerModule:

```
@Module({
  imports: [PrismaModule],
  providers: [LoggerMiddleware, PrismaService],
  exports: [LoggerMiddleware]
})
export class LoggerModule {}
```

It starts without errors and code reaches my logger middleware but then I am getting an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prisma')

I have access to Prisma service from another provider and a connection to DB works.
At the start, nest initializes all dependencies successfully but I don't understand why during execution it fell with this error. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was given by Alexander Bukhalo on [github](https://github.com/hypeertech/nestjs-telegraf/discussions/1023#discussioncomment-4448634)